# Using wildcard like folderpath/* doesn't match folderpath/. Why?

Tags: sh, wildcard, gnu-coreutils

Why doesn't `rm -fR folderpath/*` delete folderpath as well. As I understand wildcard `a*` means `a` or `a` plus any number of characters. So, `folderpath/*` means `folderpath/` and `folderpath/` plus any character. So, the command should also perform `rm -fR folderpath/` which should result in deleting folderpath as well.

Comment: The wildcard in this case is "shell globbing" where `*` matches anything, _but not **nothing**_ — it is not like `*` in regular expressions, which match "zero or more" ... the shell glob `*` does not match _zero_.

Comment: Pathname expansion works slightly differently from pattern matching.

Comment: @StephenP That's not entirely true. `foo*bar` would match `foobar`.

Comment: That's true @chepner - my bad.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the shell tries to expand your wildcards. Try it with `ls`.

Assuming you have a folder `aaa` with two subfolders `bbb1` and `bbb2` and each of them contains the files `ccc1` and `ccc2`. Would look like this:

```
└── aaa
    ├── bbb1
    │   ├── ccc1
    │   └── ccc2
    └── bbb2
        ├── ccc1
        └── ccc2
```

Let’s create them for testing:

```
mkdir -p aaa/bbb{1,2}
touch aaa/bbb{1,2}/ccc{1,2}
```

Now try what the following commands show you:

```
ls aaa        # first
ls aaa/       # second
ls aaa/*      # third
```

The first command shows you the content of `aaa`, which are the folders `bbb1` and `bbb2`. The second command does the same.

But the third command expands to

```
ls aaa/bbb1 aaa/bbb2
```

Yes, and it shows you like expected the contents of `bbb1` and `bbb2`, which are both times the files `ccc1` and `ccc2`.

What I wanted to show: Your shell substitutes the `*` with all files (or folders) in **that given directory** (because all files and folders names match) and replaces your string `aaa/*` by `aaa/bbb1 aaa/bbb2`. But it does **not** expand to `aaa`, because that would be taking the `/*` away.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation isn't clear on this point, but pathname expansion is very slightly different from ordinary pattern matching. Once you match a `/`, you must match at least one entry in the directory before the pattern as a whole can be considered to match. So although the pattern `/foo/*` would match the *string* `/foo/`, it does not match the *path* `/foo/`.

One possible interpretation is that `/foo/*` is matching *files* in `/foo/`, and if there are no files, the match fails. I would like this interpretation better, though, if

```
shopt -s dotglob
ls /foo/*
```

matched `/foo/.` and `/foo/..`.

Perhaps the correct way of thinking about it is that pathname expansion considers a `/`-delimited sequence of patterns, each of which must match *something* for the pattern as a whole to match.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only deleting what is inside folderpath the "/" implies that.

Use

```
rm -rf folderpath
```

if you want it all gone.

Comment: I know that.Just want to know why?Because rm -fR folderpath/ deletes thewhole folder.Why is wild card behaving differently for rm?